# WCF Streaming Times Out

Tags: .net, wcf, streaming

I guess to begin I should ask whether Streaming WCF works without MTOM or if MTOM is required? I was using MTOM, but it didn't work with our Mono based macOS client, so we had to turn it off.

We have a WCF web app hosted on IIS.

Here is the binding on the client:

```
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IDataService" transferMode="Streamed"
                             sendTimeout="01:05:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="504857600">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
      </security>
    </binding>
```

Here is the binding on the server:

```
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IDataService" transferMode="Streamed" sendTimeout="01:05:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="130000000">
                <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="104857600" maxStringContentLength="104857600" />
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
                </security>
            </binding>
```

I called one of the methods on the client called ReceiveAsync. It returns a stream object. I then make calls on the stream object to download the data.

The problem I have is that it appears that the call to ReceiveAsync doesn't return until the whole file is returned which seems more like Buffered than Streamed.

If this runs on a slow enough network connection, it times out on the called to ReceiveAsync.

Why doesn't the ReceiveAsync return right away and then allow my to stream the file data?

Comment: As far as I can tell I should not need MTOM. That is just the encoding for the binary data. I have also done additional debugging and it looks like even though the binding does show Streaming, the message is not streaming. The WCF method call doesn't return until it has downloaded the entire file data. So why would that happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the .net 4.5.2 implementation that is included in Visual Studio 2017 doesn't seem to support the streaming mode.

I ended up adding a REST download for large files and that works for me.